# rack-cors failing on production build

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I have an Rails 5 API project and I'm using [**`rack-cors`**](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors).

**Situation**:

I have some static JSON files in `public/files` folder, like this:

```
{
  "example": "123456"
   ...
}
```

I can access them perfectly (from Angular client) in **development**, but it doesn't work in **production**.

In **production**, I'm getting the common error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://myhost.com/files/my_file.json. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

The most stranger thing is that I can access the url (`https://myhost.com/files/my_file.json`) manually in browser without any problems.

**Actual configuration**:

*config/initializers/cors.rb:*

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins my_origins
    resource '*',
      expose: ['awesome_token'],
      headers: :any,
      methods: %i[delete get head options patch post put]
  end
end
```

**Possible configuration**:

So after some research, I found the following:

*environments/production.rb*:

```
# Added the following
config.public_file_server.enabled = true
```

*cors.rb*:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins my_origins
    resource '*',
      expose: ['awesome_token'],
      headers: :any,
      methods: %i[delete get head options patch post put]
  end
end

# Added the following
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before ActionDispatch::Static, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*',
      headers: :any,
      methods: %i[delete get head options patch post put]
  end
end
```

But it make absolutely no difference.

So, my question is: Is there something that I'm missing? What's wrong?

**PS:** Every request is working fine, the problem is with this static JSON files in `public/files` folder (in **production** build).

Comment: What are you using for your application server?

Comment: @code4fun I'm using capistrano to deploy... in application server I'm using Apache and Passenger.